# Problems upgrading from 12.04 to 14.04

Tags: upgrade

I'm a complete Linux newbie using Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop and now wanting to upgrade to 14.04. I'm having some issues and have tried googling my way out. I would really appreciate some advice but please treat me as though I am a moron as I have very little experience with linux :-( I'm really sorry to do a "tl;dr" as my first post but I don't know what is relevant and what's not.

I tried to do the upgrade from update manager but got this message:

```
Third party sources disabled
Some third party entries in your sources.list were disabled. You can re-enable them after the upgrade with the 'software-properties' tool or your package manager.
```

Followed by this message:

```
The upgrade has aborted. The upgrade needs a total of 2,195 M free space on disk '/'. Please free at least an additional 891 M of disk space on '/'. Empty your trash and remove temporary packages of former installations using 'sudo apt-get clean'.
```

The point at which the above happened was at "setting new software channels"

I emptied my rubbish bin and did

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

as instructed; Nothing happened in the terminal after that though. I'm not sure where '/' is and what I should delete on it? Nevertheless, I then tried to reinstall using update manager again but the results were the same.

I then googled a bit and did this in terminal:

```
sudo update-manager -d
```

and got this:

```
WARNING:root:nothing unsupported running 0 (0)
```

It then brought up update manager again anyway, so I clicked on upgrade again, as per my first step, but results were the same.

Thanks. The output of

> df -h

is:

`Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       7.4G  5.8G  1.3G  83% /
udev            932M  4.0K  932M   1% /dev
tmpfs           188M  920K  187M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            939M   19M  921M   2% /run/shm
/dev/sda6       220G   31G  178G  15% /home`

Really basic qu here but how do I remove things from /.?

I also did as below, and tried the upgrade again, but same results

`sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean
[sudo] password for fibie: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED
  gettext libtommath0 ttf-droid ttf-umefont ttf-unfonts-core wine-gecko1.8
  wine-gecko1.9
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 7 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
After this operation, 41.1 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 278209 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing gettext ...
Removing libtommath0 ...
Removing ttf-droid ...
Removing ttf-umefont ...
Removing ttf-unfonts-core ...
Removing wine-gecko1.8 ...
Removing wine-gecko1.9 ...
Processing triggers for install-info ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done`

Thanks

This was originally a windows pc, but I thought I uninstalled windows. I don't get offered the option of booting into windows at start-up. I don't want or need windows.

Thanks :-) How do I resize the / partition?

I just tried

> sudo do-release-upgrade

The output was HUGE but ultimately the result was the same and upgrade aborted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in a bit of a bind: Your root partition is only ~8GB, so making space in it is hard. What I suggest is that you set up a temporary mount from a folder in your home directory to `/var/cache/apt/archives/`, so that the space in your home directory partition is available for apt:

```
mkdir ~/tmp
sudo mount -o bind ~/tmp /var/cache/apt/archives/
```

This should give `apt` plenty of room.

Comment: Thanks. Will try this now. I can't run gparted as I get $ Root privileges are required for running gparted :-( What are root privs and why don't I have them?

Comment: @FiWhitchelo you have root privileges. Do `pkexec gparted`.

Comment: Thanks - the upgrade *seems* to be working, but says it will take 2 hours so I'll do it overnight. As for the gparted stuff, I'll try and sort that another time. Thanks so much to you both - markng this as resolved :-)

Comment: I'm in even more of a mess now. About 2 hours in to the upgrade, messages came up saying there were various issues and certain packages couldn't be installed. It also said it would restore the original system. But when I rebooted 14.04 seems to be there, but with multiple error notifications. I have no idea now whether I have 14.04 in its entirety (it seems not though). Please, What can I do to troubleshoot this and clean the whole mess up?

Comment: For starters, if you can login, run `sudo dpkg --configure -a; sudo apt-get install -f`. Then post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

/ is your root partition. Your entire Ubuntu installation is in /. This includes all your applications, music, pictures, videos, etc. (Your personal files are usually stored in /home/(username)/). If you can clear/copy some of those to another location, you'll free up space in /.

You could also run `sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean` to free up a little more space

Your home directory is mounted on a 220G partition and your root directory(/) is mounted on a 7.4G partition. I'd recommend resizing the / partition (/dev/sda1) to 15G or so. You can use a tool like `gparted` to resize partitions.

If you don't want to resize the partition `sudo do-release-upgrade` *might* work.

Could you post your replies as comments on this post? Otherwise the original post gets cluttered.

In that case you should install gparted by running `sudo apt-get install gparted`. Then `gparted &` to run it.

Comment: @FiWhitchelo It's really hard to read output when pasted into a comment. Please edit your question and add the output there.

Comment: @PranavMarathe  sure :-) Please can you tell me how to resize the partition? Also in terms of editing the original question or replying in comments, someone else just advised not to put output in a comment. I'm not sure what the correct format is now :-)

Comment: I also tried sudo do-release-upgrade but it aborted.

Comment: You should install gparted by running sudo apt-get install gparted. Then gparted & to run it.

Comment: See muru's answer for a one-time solution. Then you can resize the partitions at your leisure so you don't have to create temporary mounts to install new applications in the future.

Comment: I got this :-( $ Root privileges are required for running gparted.

Comment: Try `sudo gparted &`